# PHP Memory exhausted - array or sql?

Tags: php, sql, memory

I have an array that I'm appending to in a loop:

```
array_push($obj->{$type.'listings'}, $listing);
```

The loop makes a bunch of remote calls and pulls in data that I want to store in a file and use as a sort of cache.

While running this "cache routine", if I serialize this array it reports to be just over 5MB. To create the 5MB array, the script exhausts 100MB of memory. I'm being very careful to unset variables to free memory as I can.  I've went as far as commenting everything out and function by function uncommented to see where the memory build up is.  It certainly happens as I push to the array.  If I don't use the array_push, then using memory_get_usage() and gc_collect_cycles() I can see a rather steady amount of memory used with some spikes, but it frees itself as it moves along.

As soon as I push to the array, it gets all crazy and the memory usage just piles up.

Are there any ideas on how to handle a situation like this?

Can I not build large arrays like this with PHP?

Is there a way to flush the array to a file while I'm building it? And lets assume that I could get it built and stored in a file.  When I want to use it, will i use the same amount of resources once pulled from the file....or is the memory exhaustion just happening because it's dynamically being added to as it's being built?

Is this something that I should just consider using SQL for? and storing each run of the loop in a separate row?

Just for kicks,  I added: `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` just to see if it would run.

It did, and memory usage peaked at just over 100 MB, with a serialized object size of just over 8MB.   Now, this isn't really helpful as I am just processing a sample of data and this could grow to be much bigger.

Anyway, any thoughts you might have on optimizing a situation like this would be great.

Comment: You say you're being careful about unsetting stuff - are you freeing your mySQL result? That tends to suck memory too if you do it enough.

Comment: I'm not storing anything in SQL as of now.  I was just asking if that is a better route to go.  But there are some sql queries in getting the data, and to free them I am using unset($result) where $result holds the result set

Comment: I never said that. What I meant was using something like `mySQLi_Result::Free()` or whatever you use - not particularly sure if unset() will totally free the memory in your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 5MB of array PHP doens't use 100MB for sure.

Use http://it.php.net/memory_get_usage in your script to see where it grows

Consider I build in PHP arrays of millions (2 millions) of entry without problems. (memory usage less than 200MB)

Comment: Yeah, well, that's what I figured as far as a 5MB serialized object not taking up 100MB of memory. I have been using memory_get_usage to try and trouble shoot this, and it seems that it just grows as I add to the array.  Confused on this one.

Comment: it's pretty unredable there with automatic new line

Comment: Yeah, there's a button to toggle line wrapping.

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is.  It still eats up tons of memory building the arrays.  I just set "no limit" on the memory and it seems to work.  We'll see what happens when I start getting larger data in.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you are using a foreach loop to iterate your through a list like so:

```
foreach($list AS $value)
{
   $list[] = trim($item);
}
```

You can potentially infinitely increase the size of `$list`, thus causes an infinite, or near infinite loop. When a script with loops consumes more memory then it should, its usually caused by a loop building a list too large for memory to handle.

Answer (score -2):

Using a serialized array of several megabytes of data as a "sort of cache" is apparently bad idea.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a big array being cached: it might even give your a serious performance boost.

Comment: Thanks Robin.  The main reason for wanting to cache the data is to not have to do all the remote procedures everytime a page loads.  So by caching the data locally...well, it's just necessary

Comment: @RobinUS2 oh surely there is nothing wrong. Except of consuming a lot of memory and hellovalot of parsing :)

Comment: @SenicaGonzalez Asking a question, one have to read answers attentively. Nobody said you shouldn't use cache. It's the way you choose is apparently wrong. Can you see the difference?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Unserializing in PHP does cause some overhead in PHP using memory, however it's pretty quick. The slow part in the whole serialize-thing is the serialize() itself. One of the main reasons frameworks like Zend enable auto_serialization for their Cache frontends.